# Почему не подключаются скрипты в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

пытаюсь подключить скрпиты ,прописал все верно,ничего не пропустил,но ничего не получается.

```
<?php 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'style_theme' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'scripts_theme' );

function style_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/default.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/layout.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'media-queries', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/media-queries.css' );        
}

function scripts_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'doubletaptogo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/doubletaptogo.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/init.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/modernizr.js' );

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

В теме должны быть `wp_head()` и `wp_footer()` именно на эти ф-ции выводятся стили/скрипты. И лучше использовать `wp_enqueue_scripts` для подключения скриптов, но в ф-ции wp_enqueue_script указывать 5-й параметр true (in footer). Например:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'doubletaptogo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/doubletaptogo.js', [], '1.0.0', true );
```

Comment: И третий параметр лучше указывать, чтоб `doubletaptogo` завелся)

Comment: wp_head() я поставил  перед </head> и wp_footer() поставил перед </body>

Comment: @ИгорьИльин Значит проблема в опечатке какой-то, за вас мы ее не найдем

Comment: @ИгорьИльин а как ты понял, что скрипты не подключаются? Если они просто не работают то они и не должны